# Power Query - Replacing specific value based on another column

Tags: excel, powerbi, formula, powerquery

As the title suggest, I'd like to replace the **values of column x** that contain in **Text - Copy** with "" (Blank/null)

[image]

I've tried the following but it does not seems to work to my ideal result.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Duplicated Column",each [x],"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Text - Copy"})
```

This would be the ideal result that I'd like to yield

[image]

I've tried to use this as was given, but it doesnt yield the ideal result.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Duplicated Column",each [x],"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text - Copy"})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Replacer.ReplaceText` for replacer as function

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Duplicated Column",each [x],"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Text - Copy"})
```

Comment: I've tried this but it doesnt work. It shows up a column of error. I've edited the question to show a picture of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Custom Column:

*Assuming `Text - Copy` is your duplicated column which you want to process*

```
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Text", "Text - Copy"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Custom", 
        each try 
            Text.Combine(
                List.RemoveMatchingItems(
                    Text.Split([#"Text - Copy"]," "),
                    Table.Column(#"Duplicated Column","x")),
             " ")
        otherwise null)
```